# Labels not showing correct name

Tags: tensorflow, label, object-recognition

i am pretty new to this all so bare with me here.

I've made myself a program to recognise tools, issue is, while running it will see the object, but the name will be N/A, note that this doesn't happen to every label (doesn't recognise screwdrivers yet but when it thinks it sees one, it does label it Screwdriver instead of N/A)

Now, I've checked countless forums from people with this issue and i cannot find why this is happening.
I have 16 classes for the 16 objects, labelmap is in order and exactly as shown on multiple other sites.

All out of idea's here ..

:pipeline:

> ```
> model {   ssd {
> num_classes: 16
> image_resizer {
>   keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
>     min_dimension: 512
>     max_dimension: 512
>     pad_to_max_dimension: false
>   }
> }
> feature_extractor {
>   type: "ssd_efficientnet-b0_bifpn_keras"
>   conv_hyperparams {
>     regularizer {
>       l2_regularizer {
>         weight: 4e-05
>       }
>     }
>     initializer {
>       truncated_normal_initializer {
>         mean: 0.0
>         stddev: 0.03
>       }
>     }
>     activation: SWISH
>     batch_norm {
>       decay: 0.99
>       scale: true
>       epsilon: 0.001
>     }
>     force_use_bias: true
>   }
>   bifpn {
>     min_level: 3
>     max_level: 7
>     num_iterations: 3
>     num_filters: 64
>   }
> }
> box_coder {
>   faster_rcnn_box_coder {
>     y_scale: 10.0
>     x_scale: 10.0
>     height_scale: 5.0
>     width_scale: 5.0
>   }
> }
> matcher {
>   argmax_matcher {
>     matched_threshold: 0.5
>     unmatched_threshold: 0.5
>     ignore_thresholds: false
>     negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
>     force_match_for_each_row: true
>     use_matmul_gather: true
>   }
> }
> similarity_calculator {
>   iou_similarity {
>   }
> }
> box_predictor {
>   weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
>     conv_hyperparams {
>       regularizer {
>         l2_regularizer {
>           weight: 4e-05
>         } 
>       }
>       initializer {
>         random_normal_initializer {
>           mean: 0.0
>           stddev: 0.01
>         }
>       }
>       activation: SWISH
>       batch_norm {
>         decay: 0.99
>         scale: true
>         epsilon: 0.001
>       }
>       force_use_bias: true
>     }
>     depth: 64
>     num_layers_before_predictor: 3
>     kernel_size: 3
>     class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
>     use_depthwise: true
>   }
> }
> anchor_generator {
>   multiscale_anchor_generator {
>     min_level: 3
>     max_level: 7
>     anchor_scale: 4.0
>     aspect_ratios: 1.0
>     aspect_ratios: 2.0
>     aspect_ratios: 0.5
>     scales_per_octave: 3
>   }
> }
> post_processing {
>   batch_non_max_suppression {
>     score_threshold: 1e-08
>     iou_threshold: 0.5
>     max_detections_per_class: 100
>     max_total_detections: 100
>   }
>   score_converter: SIGMOID
> }
> normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
> loss {
>   localization_loss {
>     weighted_smooth_l1 {
>     }
>   }
>   classification_loss {
>     weighted_sigmoid_focal {
>       gamma: 1.5
>       alpha: 0.25
>     }
>   }
>   classification_weight: 1.0
>   localization_weight: 1.0
> }
> encode_background_as_zeros: true
> normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
> inplace_batchnorm_update: true
> freeze_batchnorm: false
> add_background_class: false   } } train_config {   batch_size: 1   data_augmentation_options {
> random_horizontal_flip {
> }   }   data_augmentation_options {
> random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
>   output_size: 512
>   scale_min: 0.1
>   scale_max: 2.0
> }   }   sync_replicas: true   optimizer {
> momentum_optimizer {
>   learning_rate {
>     cosine_decay_learning_rate {
>       learning_rate_base: 0.08
>       total_steps: 300000
>       warmup_learning_rate: 0.001
>       warmup_steps: 2500
>     }
>   }
>   momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
> }
> use_moving_average: false   }   fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:/Users/djust/Desktop/Object_detection/models/research/object_detection/efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
> ```
>
> num_steps: 300000   startup_delay_steps: 0.0   replicas_to_aggregate:
> 8   max_number_of_boxes: 100   unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
> fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"   use_bfloat16: false
> fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2 } train_input_reader {
> label_map_path:
> "C:/Users/djust/Desktop/Object_detection/models/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
> tf_record_input_reader {
> input_path: "C:/Users/djust/Desktop/Object_detection/models/research/object_detection/train.record"
> } } eval_config {   metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
> use_moving_averages: false   batch_size: 1 } eval_input_reader {
> label_map_path:
> "C:/Users/djust/Desktop/Object_detection/models/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
> shuffle: false   num_epochs: 1   tf_record_input_reader {
> input_path: "C:/Users/djust/Desktop/Object_detection/models/research/object_detection/test.record"
> } }

:Labelmap:

> item {
> display_name: 'person'
> name: 'person'
> id: 1 } item {
> display_name: 'crimping_tool'
> name: 'crimping_tool'
> id: 2 } item {
> display_name: 'drill_set'
> name: 'drill_set'
> id: 3 } item {
> display_name: 'utility_knife'
> name: 'utility_knife'
> id: 4 } item {
> display_name: 'screwdriver'
> name: 'screwdriver'
> id: 5 } item {
> display_name: 'stripping_pliers'
> name: 'stripping_pliers'
> id: 6 } item {
> display_name: 'cutting_pliers'
> name: 'cutting_pliers'
> id: 7 } item {
> display_name: 'stripping_tool'
> name: 'stripping_tool'
> id: 8 } item {
> display_name: 'pliers'
> name: 'pliers'
> id: 9 } item {
> display_name: 'pipewrench'
> name: 'pipewrench'
> id: 10 } item {
> display_name: 'measuring_tool'
> name: 'measuring_tool'
> id: 11 } item {
> display_name: 'cable_cutter_angled'
> name: 'cable_cutter_angled'
> id: 12 } item {
> display_name: 'stripping_tool_2'
> name: 'stripping_tool_2'
> id: 13 } item {
> display_name: 'wrench'
> name: 'wrench'
> id: 14 } item {
> display_name: 'hexkey_set'
> name: 'hexkey_set'
> id: 15 } item {
> display_name: 'drill_set_2'
> name: 'drill_set_2'
> id: 16 }

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause could be that in the TFrecords that you use the "label ID" is not correct. Can you validate that when converting your images and annotations to those TF records that the 'image/object/class/label' is set correctly?

```
'image/object/class/label':
    dataset_util.int64_list_feature(category_ids)
```

I also noticed there is a "display_name" in your labelmap file, I've never used the display_name and I'm not sure if that could also be a cause of your N/A labels.

If the labels are correctly set in the tfrecord, then I would advise to try a labelmap file with the following structure:
item {
id: 1
name: 'person'
}

item {
id: 2
name: 'crimping_tool'
}

item {
id: 3
name: 'drill_set'
}

...

Comment: Fixed it yesterday!

I managed to mix up the path to the untrained model and the trained model.. so each time running it, it would use the untrained model haha

The display_name thing i didn't use at first either, but once i saw it a few times on some forum posts i thought i'd try it to see if that would fix it.


Thinking about it now though, how come it did sometimes show things such as screwdriver and drill_set if it was using the untrained model?
regardless, the N/A's are gone now which was the issue.